# Configure hibernate 3.6 dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven-2, maven

I want to use hibernate 3.6 but I can't configure it properly 
With my maven configuration

```
   <hibernate.version>3.6.6.Final</hibernate.version>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

I get

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet springapp threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1699)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 ....

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
 ...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.MappingException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
    ...
```

I use it together with `spring 3.0.5.RELEASE`, if it matter. What does I miss?

**UPD**
I added spring-orm to my dependencies, but it diddn't help
Exception is throwing when I try inject EntityManager directly 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

```
@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Or when I try using Spring Data Project `Repository`.
My configuration

```
<!-- Instructs Spring to perfrom declarative transaction managemenet on annotated classes -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Drives transactions using local JPA APIs -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="rollbackOnCommitFailure" value="true"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Creates a EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider and a simple in-memory data source populated with test data -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="reportsPersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendor"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>

<!-- DataSource configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someProj?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="user" value="someUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="somePass"/>
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="20"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="25"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="250"/>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="true"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="600"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="reportsPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

`User` is a simple JPA entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    private long id = -1;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (id != user.id) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also have the spring-orm.jar as a dependency?

Comment: @blong824 No. I add it but tt didn't help. Additional info provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you're running or what you're doing to get that error. MappingException [comes from hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22org.hibernate.MappingException%22), so your dependencies aren't the problem. However and whatever you're running isn't correctly using the Maven classpath.

Comment: @Msaleh Unfortunately, I can not. Try run with clean or recreate project from pom if you are using IDE.

Comment: i deleted the dependencies and downloaded them again and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use hibernate with JPA annotations and I only need to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
    <version>3.6.6.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

There is no need for entries `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` and `persistence-api`. Keep `hibernate-entitymanager` if you are using the EntityManager.

I also have an entry for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <spring-ws.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
            <springbatch-core.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</springbatch-core.version>
            <spring-security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
            <hibernate-core.version>4.2.4.Final</hibernate-core.version>

            <jsp-api.version>2.1</jsp-api.version>

            <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.3</ojdbc6.version>
            <persistence-api.version>1.0</persistence-api.version>
            <apache-commons.version>3.1</apache-commons.version>

            </properties>
    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${springbatch-core.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                        <version>${springbatch-core.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency><dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
                </dependency>
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${persistence-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>${apache-commons.version}</version>
                </dependency>

Add Above Dependency and also add below transaction manager configuration in dao xml:

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
        <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean ">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
            <value>com.abc.data.MyClass</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/jdbc/ExampleDS" />
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Could you format and indent your answer, and add an explanation?